# ¿Por qué se genera el error floating point exception (core dumped)?

Tags: c

Estaba tratando de resolver un problema de project Euler ([el numero 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3)), pero me sale el error que se indica "*floating point exception (core dumped)*". A decir verdad no sé la razon de que me salga este error (soy nuevo en C y programación en general), este es el codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fprimos(long long int x){
    long long int i;
    int f;
    while (i < x){
        i++;
        if (x % i == 0){
            f++;
        }
    }
    if (f == 2){
        printf("%lli, es primo", x);
    }else {
        printf("%lli", x);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main (){
    long long int number = 600851475143;
    long long int c;
    long long int v;
    long long int factores[v];

    for (c=0; c < number; c++){
        if(number % c == 0){
            factores[v] = c;
            fprimos(factores[v]);
            v++;
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long long int v;
long long int factores[v];
```

Nota que `v` no tiene un valor asignado en el momento de declarar `factores`, luego el tamaño que tendrá finalmente `factores` será un auténtico misterio.

Para poder crear `factores` con un tamaño que permita almacenar `v` elementos antes tenemos que conocer qué valor va a tener `v`. Adicionalmente deberías usar memoria dinámica, ya que tu diseño actual tiene dos problemas:

- No es conforme al estándar, luego no tiene por qué compilar en todos los sistemas (aparte de que puede no funcionar como esperas)
- `factores` lo estás creando en la pila. Si `v` almacenase un valor grande, la pila podría desbordarse.

Corregido sería así:

```
int v = 0; // No creo que necesites más de 2^31 factores

// Inicialmente solo almacenará un elmento
long long int * factores = (long long int*)malloc(sizeof(long long int));

for (c=0; c < number; c++){
    if(number % c == 0){
        factores[v] = c;
        fprimos(factores[v]);
        v++;

        // Incrementamos la cantidad de memoria asignada a factores
        factores = (long long int*)realloc(factores, (v+1)*sizeof(long long int));
      }
}

free(factores);
```

Con esto en principio ya estaría. Eso sí, notarás que el rendimiento puede llegar a ser bastante pobre. El problema de esta solución es que la asignación de memoria dinámica es un proceso lento. Si el tiempo es un factor importante es importante reducir el número de llamadas a `malloc` y `realloc`.

El siguiente ejemplo reduce el número de asignaciones al 10%

```
int v = 0; // No creo que necesites más de 2^31 factores

// Inicialmente almacenará hasta 10 elementos
long long int * factores = (long long int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(long long int));

for (c=0; c < number; c++){
    if(number % c == 0){
        factores[v] = c;
        fprimos(factores[v]);
        v++;

        // Incrementamos, únicamente cuando hayamos llenado el array
        if (v % 10 == 0)
            factores = (long long int*)realloc(factores, (v+10)*sizeof(long long int));
      }
}

free(factores);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu respuesta si me funciono

Comment: @Arslong-Vitabrevis si una respuesta te soluciona el problema, no olvides marcarla como solución. Un saludo